# Javascript creating an array in a flat format based on multiple levels

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart like in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/fct1p8j8/4/

The chart it self works just fine when hard coding the data, everything is good there.

I am struggling to figure out how to get the data in the correct format from my database structure.

Here is an example output of my data setup:

```
[
  {
    "invDept": "Due Diligence",
    "programs": {
      "data": [
        {
          "program": "Brand Risk Management",
          "total": "1847"
        },
        {
          "program": "Due Diligence",
          "total": "2718"
        },
        {
          "program": "SAR",
          "total": "17858"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "invDept": "Sanctions",
    "programs": {
      "data": [
        {
          "program": "Brand Risk Management",
          "total": "500"
        },
        {
          "program": "Due Diligence",
          "total": "2100"
        },
        {
          "program": "SAR",
          "total": "16593"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The x axis will be the `invDepartment` value which come from the object.
The series data is what I need to craft into the necessary format for the chart.

For each department, I need the value of each program in an array format.

For example, `Brand Risk Management` is the program name and I need the value of it from both the `Due Diligence` department and the `Sanctions` department.

I started with doing a basic loop to create the array structure like so:

// Get our departments for the X Axis

```
$.each(data.data, function (key, value) {

    d = value;

    xAxis.push(value.invDept);

    // If an array for the department doesn't exist, create it now
    if (typeof res[d.invDept] == "undefined" || !(res[d.invDept] instanceof Array)) {
        res[d.invDept] = [];
    }

});
```

From here I have something like:

```
res['Due Diligence'] = []
```

I am stuck at this point. Not quite sure how I need to set up my loops to get this data in the flat format.

The final output would be like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Brand Risk Management',
    data: [1847, 500]
}, {
    name: 'Due Diligence',
    data: [2718, 2100]
}, {
    name: 'SAR',
    data: [17858, 16593]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to flatten the data to a single array.

Then [reduces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that merges objects with the same key into the desired result. When done, converts the Map back to array with [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) and the spread syntax.

```js
const data = [{"invDept":"Due Diligence","programs":{"data":[{"program":"Brand Risk Management","total":"1847"},{"program":"Due Diligence","total":"2718"},{"program":"SAR","total":"17858"},{"program":"Sanctions - WLM","total":"885"}]}},{"invDept":"Sanctions","programs":{"data":[{"program":"Brand Risk Management","total":"500"},{"program":"Due Diligence","total":"2100"},{"program":"SAR","total":"16593"},{"program":"Sanctions - WLM","total":"443"}]}}]

const result = [... // spread the iterator to a new array
  // flatten the array
  [].concat(...data.map(({ programs }) => programs.data))
  // reduce the data into a map
  .reduce((r, { program: name, total }) => {
      // if key doesn't exist create the object
      r.has(name) || r.set(name, { name, data: [] }) 
      // get the object, and add the total to the data array
      r.get(name).data.push(total) 

      return r;
    }, new Map())
  .values()] // get the Map's values iterator
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce`.

```js
var array = [  {    "invDept": "Due Diligence",    "programs": {      "data": [        {          "program": "Brand Risk Management",          "total": "1847"        },        {          "program": "Due Diligence",          "total": "2718"        },        {          "program": "SAR",          "total": "17858"        }      ]    }  },  {    "invDept": "Sanctions",    "programs": {      "data": [        {          "program": "Brand Risk Management",          "total": "500"        },        {          "program": "Due Diligence",          "total": "2100"        },        {          "program": "SAR",          "total": "16593"        }      ]    }  }],
    result = { series: Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => {
      c.programs.data.forEach((d) => 
        (a[d.program] || (a[d.program] = {data: [], name: d.program})).data.push(d.total));
      return a;
}, {}))};

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to iterate through your array and store your values in an object accumulator. Iterate `programs` `data` using `array#forEach` and populate the object accumulator. Then extract out all the values using `Object.values()`

```js
var data = [ { "invDept": "Due Diligence", "programs": { "data": [ { "program": "Brand Risk Management", "total": "1847" }, { "program": "Due Diligence", "total": "2718" }, { "program": "SAR", "total": "17858" }, { "program": "Sanctions - WLM", "total": "885" }] } }, { "invDept": "Sanctions", "programs": { "data": [ { "program": "Brand Risk Management", "total": "500" }, { "program": "Due Diligence", "total": "2100" }, { "program": "SAR", "total": "16593" }, { "program": "Sanctions - WLM", "total": "443" }] } } ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      o.programs.data.forEach(({program, total}) => {
        r[program] = r[program] || {name: program, data: []};
        r[program].data.push(total);
      });
      return r;
    },{})),
    output = {series: result};
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method and store each program in a new object as the key to its array. I couldn't tell if you wanted duplicates, but if not you would simply replace the `array object` for a `set object` and `push` for `add`

```
let myPrograms = data.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
item && item.programs && item.programs.data && accumulateData(item.programs.data);

function accumulateData(program_data) {
  for (let item of program_data) {
    accumulator[item.program] ||
      (accumulator[item.program] = [item.total],
        accumulator[item.program].push(item.total));
  }
}
return accumulator;
}, {});
```

You can access the array of data inside `myPrograms` like this:

```
myPrograms["name of program"];
```

```js
let data = [{
    "invDept": "Due Diligence",
    "programs": {
      "data": [{
          "program": "Brand Risk Management",
          "total": "1847"
        },
        {
          "program": "Due Diligence",
          "total": "2718"
        },
        {
          "program": "SAR",
          "total": "17858"
        },
        {
          "program": "Sanctions - WLM",
          "total": "885"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "invDept": "Sanctions",
    "programs": {
      "data": [{
          "program": "Brand Risk Management",
          "total": "500"
        },
        {
          "program": "Due Diligence",
          "total": "2100"
        },
        {
          "program": "SAR",
          "total": "16593"
        },
        {
          "program": "Sanctions - WLM",
          "total": "443"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

let myPrograms = data.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  item&&item.programs&&item.programs.data&& 
  accumulateData(item.programs.data);

  function accumulateData(program_data) {
    for (let item of program_data) {
      accumulator[item.program] || (accumulator[item.program] = [item.total], accumulator[item.program].push(item.total));
    }
  } 
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(myPrograms);
console.log(myPrograms["Brand Risk Management"]);
```